# change UISegmentedControl, with reference, title

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have segmented control described in XIB (in storyboard exactly) and has reference to controller class. I am trying to change segmented control titles according to language, but I can't change it. When i log my segmented control, it says it don't have any segments, even I have made them in XIB or create programatically. Does anybody know whats wrong?

code:

```
NSLog(@"segments:%d", [segmentControl numberOfSegments]);
[segmentControl removeAllSegments];
[segmentControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"stuff" atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segmentControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"other stuff" atIndex:1 animated:NO];
NSLog(@"segments:%d", [segmentControl numberOfSegments]);
```

both logs outputs shows zeroes

Comment: Xibs and Storyboards are not the same thing.

Comment: I know they have difference, but it doesn't matter this time

Comment: When are you logging the number of segments? Are you sure that the control has been initialized and connected to your outlet? (I.e. please add `NSLog(@"%@", segmentControl);` before your the other log statements)

Comment: This code piece is in viewDidLoad method. Your log result is (null). So it looks like it is not initialized even it shows up in simulator

Comment: i think this is something to do with localization. I played half day with it till it worked. Now I can't change layout even un storyboard. I think there is somewhere another copy which is being used while I can find only one storyboard in en.Iproj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that problem was not i code, but in storyboard itself (I played half day with localization)

I found that even I had one storyboard, but it being in en.Iproj made mess (looks like another language couldn't reach it). I took it out to main folder and now everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)loadView
    {
            [super loadView];
            UISegmentedControl *seg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                       [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"111", @"2222", @"333", nil]];
            seg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50);
            [seg addTarget:self action:@selector(changed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [self.view addSubview:seg];
            [seg release];
    }

    - (void)changed:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentControl
    {
            NSLog(@"segments:%d", [segmentControl numberOfSegments]);
            [segmentControl removeAllSegments];
            [segmentControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"stuff" atIndex:0 animated:NO];
            [segmentControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"other stuff" atIndex:1 animated:NO];
            NSLog(@"segments:%d", [segmentControl numberOfSegments]);
    }
```

Your code works fine.